# How to map mice buttons via keyboard, Linux

Tags: linux, x11, xorg, mouse, xinput

I use Debian 9 (aka 'Stretch') x86_64.

```
$ uname -a:  
Linux mypc 4.9.0-8-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.9.130-2 (2018-10-27) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Tried to map my extra button from my device, Logitech MU-007 :

```
$ lsusb | grep Logitech  
Bus 001 Device 023: ID 046d:c069 Logitech, Inc. M-U0007 [Corded Mouse M500]
```

xinput device :

```
$ xinput | grep Logitech  
⎜   ↳ Logitech USB Laser Mouse                  id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]
```

Test of extra buttons with `xinput test 10` return 8 and 9 for the two buttons of the left side of the mice.

```
$ xinput -version  
xinput version 1.6.2
```

Tried a simple :

```
xinput set-button-map 10 8 2 3
```

or

```
$ xmodmap -e "pointer = 9 2 3"
Warning: Only changing the first 3 of 12 buttons.
X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)
  Major opcode of failed request:  116 (X_SetPointerMapping)
  Value in failed request:  0x9
  Serial number of failed request:  9
  Current serial number in output stream:
```

The left buttons do not work at all, can't select with those like left click.

I would like to keep left click AND extra buttons as left click too.
Any idea why the `xinput` command didn't select anything ?

### EDIT

Finally:

```
id=$(xinput list | grep -oP 'Logitech USB Laser Mouse.*id=\K\d+')
xinput set-button-map $id 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 1 1 10 11 12
```

Comment: What desktop environment do you use? If it has a mouse settings tool, the desktop environment might be overriding your command-line settings.

Comment: I use cinnamon, post edited accordingly. Added xmodmap way too, more verbose. @telcoM; do you know a workaround ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a better solution. **I can this way keep numeric keypad** that is not possible with other solutions.

I have a keyboard key to switch between [mousekeys mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mouse_keys), that way, I use F1 as left click, F2 as middle click and F3 as right click. Then I can switch back to keypad with the special key.

The special key trigger this script (check your WM keyboards shortcuts preferences).

```
#!/bin/bash

if [[ ! -s ~/.button-state ]]; then
    echo 0 > ~/.button-state
fi

state=$(<~/.button-state)

if ((state==0)); then
    xkbset m
    yad --notification xxx &
    echo 1 > ~/.button-state
elif ((state==1)); then
    xkbset -m
    pkill -f 'yad --notification xxx
    echo 0 > ~/.button-state
else
    echo >&2 "weird error"
    exit 1
fi
```

When mouse gestures are enabled, I have this icon in system tray :

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You assumed this command would map the function of the first mouse button to physical button #8:

```
xinput set-button-map 10 8 2 3
```

This assumption is incorrect. In fact the command works exactly the opposite way: you actually set physical button #1 to send events as another instance of "button 8", which effectively made the "first mouse button" action unavailable.

If you want to make the physical button #8 to act as an extra "first mouse button", you'll have to do it this way:

```
xinput set-button-map 10 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 1 9 10 11 12
```

The default mapping is `1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12`, so if you want the physical button #8 to act the same as the first mouse button, you replace the number `8` in the mapping with another `1`.

If you want to completely disable a particular button, use `0` in the slot corresponding to that physical button.

Note that buttons 4 and 5 usually correspond to mouse wheel up/down actions.